# Why Unity application not opens over time?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile-application

I lots of times was developing different games with Unity. Than I deployed applications to mobile phones to test/play them. And I noticed, that on both platforms iOS and Android, after some time (approx. week maybe). Application not opens anymore. Do someone knows why this happen?

It's definitely not code issue, because I had 2 different computers, also worked with 4 different Unity versions and did different games. And all of them were not working after a while. Does anybody met this issue too?

Comment: Your iOS application might stop working depending on what certificate you signed it with. Not sure why Android would stop.

Comment: The other possibility is that iOS updated to a new version and now the applications are out of date.